# What is the right way to write a wrapper module for conditional OO module loading?

Tags: perl, oop, portability, perl-module, overhead

Which way should I use?

```
package My_Module;

# way one
my $package = $^O eq 'MSWin32' ? 'My_Module::Win32' : 'My_Module::Linux';
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return $package->new( @_ );
}

# way two
use parent $^O eq 'MSWin32' ? 'My_Module::Win32' : 'My_Module::Linux';
```

Comment: Neither. The My_Module object should contain a My_Module::Win32 or My_Module::Linux object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I'd go with the first technique. Creating a class that sometimes inherits from one parent, and sometimes inherits from another, seems a little dirty to me. It'll *work* certainly, but it will confuse class analysis tools (like [Pod::Coverage::CountParents](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod%3a%3aCoverage%3a%3aCountParents)) no end.

That said, I'd probably rename `sub new` to something like `new_by_platform`. There's a strong expectation that `My_Module->new` will return an object of type `My_Module`. Having it return an object of another class could confuse people. (Though if `My_Module::Win32` and `My_Module::Linux` inherit from `My_Module`, then naming it `new` seems less bad.)

Answer (score 0):

## 2 - use parent is the better way to go about it.

http://lo-f.at/glahn/2009/08/useBaseAnduseParent.html

Comment: `use parent` is less crufty than `use base`, sure, but this doesn't answer the question at all. The question doesn't mention `use base`. The question is comparing using a "factory class" with using inheritance.